# BigQuery Nested Table if Key is null remove from nested table

Tags: google-bigquery

Easy question (hope so)

I have a nested table, which looks like this:

[image]

AND WHEN DWHKey is null product array should look like this for this row (empty instead of null):

```
"product": []
```

Do not Work ((

```
ARRAY_AGG(pr IGNORE NULLS) as product
```

THIS JOIN WHAT I'M DOING:

```
SELECT 
                        x.SourceSystemCode
                        ...
                        ,product
                        ,payment
                    FROM (
                        SELECT 
                            he.SourceSystemCode
                            ...
                            ,ARRAY_AGG(pr IGNORE NULLS) as product
                    FROM header_table as he
                    LEFT JOIN product_table AS pr ON pr.DWHKey = he.DWHKey
                    GROUP BY he.SourceSystemCode..
                    ) x
                    JOIN (
                        SELECT 
                            he.SourceSystemCode
                            ...
                            ,ARRAY_AGG(pay IGNORE NULLS) AS payment  
                        FROM header_table as he
                        LEFT JOIN payment_table AS pay ON pay.DWHKey = he.DWHKey
                        GROUP BY he.SourceSystemCode...
                    ) y
                    ON x.DWHKey = y.DWHKey
```

Comment: DWHKey could be in multiple objects within this array. What if it exists in one occasion but is null in another within the same array? `product : [{key:123},{key:null}]`

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann All that I need is if NO products to join, then keep it blank not null values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use below approach:

```sql
with data as (
select '2019-1-1' CreateDate, [struct<DWHKey string, LineNumber int64>("hasKey", 1), (null, null)] product union all
select '2019-1-2', [struct<DWHKey string, LineNumber int64>(null, null), (null, null), (null, null)] union all
select '2019-1-2', [struct<DWHKey string, LineNumber int64>("hasKey", 1), (null, null), ("hasKey", 1), (null, null)] 
) 
select * 
  replace (array(select as struct * from unnest(product) where DWHKey is not null) as product) 
from data;
```

Output:

```
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CreateDate |                                   product                                   |
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2019-1-1   |                                      [{"DWHKey":"hasKey","LineNumber":"1"}] |
| 2019-1-2   |                                                                          [] |
| 2019-1-2   | [{"DWHKey":"hasKey","LineNumber":"1"},{"DWHKey":"hasKey","LineNumber":"1"}] |
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: That's the perfect answer, but you might know the way to do it initially in the nested table generation process??

Comment: @OksanaOk If you don't want null, maybe you want to replace `LEFT JOIN` with `JOIN`?

Comment: Then I will lose some of the records, I need left join but with empty instead of nulls )))

Comment: While I'm thinking about something better, this should work (in a ugly way): `ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY_AGG(pr)) WHERE DWHKey is not null) as product`

Comment: This is what I have used currently ) Thank you, and yes please let me know if you will find a clean way... Thank you in advanced

Comment: Ha! `array_agg(IF(pr.DWHKey is NULL, NULL, pr) IGNORE NULLS)` . @OksanaOk

Comment: That's awesome !